# Reducing Independent Set to a problem to prove that it is NP complete

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete

Given:

- A set of available customers $c_1, c_2, \dots, c_n$.
- A set of available foods $f_1, f_2, \dots, f_m$.
- Each customer will choose a subset of the available food.

Problem:

- Find the maximum number of customers that can be chosen, such that no two customers share the same food.

Question:

- How to reduce the independent set problem to this problem, in order to prove that this is an NP-Complete problem ?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: try to reduce each vertex to a customer and each edge to an available food.